# Rename Submodel in Studio 2.0

Tags: bricklink-studio

Is it possible to rename a submodel in BrickLink's [Studio 2.0](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/build/studio.page)? I couldn't find any appropriate function within the program.

Last time I've done it the "hard" way by modifying the .ldr files within the .io archive (the archive password can easily be found "out there"). But that should not be the recommended way, should it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's as simple as:

Right click on the submodel in the step list → rename.

I don't know, why I didn't see this earlier. I would bet, I tried that before.  ;-)

Comment: I don't blame you for missing it, though. It's a bit unfortunate that the option doesn't appear in the context menu when right-clicking the submodel directly in the 3D view.

Comment: You're right, indeed, @ChristianRau.